# How to write a recursive method to check this scenario?

Tags: java, recursion

This is my scenario. I have the following object;

```
public class MyTemplate{

private MyTemplate[]childTemplates;
}
```

Now within the same class i have an array that holds the child elements of the same object which in this case is a template. What i need is to be able to iterate through each element and elements within those elements because this can be like a tree structure. I at the moment cannot think of a way in which i can cover each and every child elements within elements.

Appreciate if anyone can direct me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
public class MyTemplate
{
  private MyTemplate[] childTemplates;

  void iterate()
  {
    // do something with this
    for (MyTemplate template: childTemplates)
      template.iterate();
  }
}
```

Comment: each template itself can have children of its own and it goes on. how do i traverse each branch and sub-branches?

Comment: oh yea. Sorry having a retarded day today :D. Thx alot for the help. This works like a charm. Recursive methods always seem to bemuse me :). Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can also carry out a process with each template:

```
public class MyTemplate
{
  private MyTemplate[] childTemplates;

  void iterate()
  {
    preProcess();
    for (MyTemplate template: childTemplates)
      template.iterate();
    postProcess();
  }

  void preProcess()
  {
    // do something before iterating through the children
  }

  void postProcess()
  {
    // do something afterwards
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks , this works too. Appreciate the time take for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public traverse() {
    if(children == null || children.size == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < children.size; i++) {
       children[i].doSomething();
       children[i].traverse();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the help Amir. Specially the part of handling the empty scenario.